Indentation of verbatim environment result in additional empty line before the following content, why?
At first, I added an indent to the verbatim environment, code is shown below:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Some text before the verbatim environment.
    \begin{verbatim*} % <--indented verbatim environment
        This is a verbatim environment containing some code or text. % <--indented verbatim environment
    \end{verbatim*} % <--indented verbatim environment
    Some text after the verbatim environment.
\end{document}

To describe the issue better, I use the verbatim* environment as it can output blank characters. compilation result show that an additional empty line before the following content is outputed, see the picture below (red circle area):

Well, when I delete the indentation, the empty line disppears, code and compilation result are shown below:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Some text before the verbatim environment.
\begin{verbatim*}
    This is a verbatim environment containing some code or text.
\end{verbatim*}
    Some text after the verbatim environment.
\end{document}


Can anyone explain the phenomenon decribed above ?

The space characters before \end{verbatim} have effect.

you are right, the newline character before \end{verbatim} is outputed.

LaTeX ain't Java or C. Indenting the source might seem appealing to people accustomed to programming languages, but TeX is aimed at typesetting, so spaces are significant, whereas in Java or C source code they're mostly ignored except being used to separate keywords.
However, some spaces in TeX are generally ignored, namely those at the beginning of a line. Except, now you'd be able to guess, inside verbatim blocks. Suppose you want to reproduce
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int first = 10;
    int second = 20;

    // add two numbers
    int sum = first + second;
    System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = "  + sum);
  }
}

You don't want that spaces at the beginning of lines are ignored, do you?
How I'd type this
Indenting by four spaces the whole document environment is completely unnecessary and shortens precious screen space. Blank lines are more effective, in my opinion.
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna.
\begin{verbatim*}
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int first = 10;
    int second = 20;

    // add two numbers
    int sum = first + second;
    System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = "  + sum);
  }
}
\end{verbatim*}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.

\end{document}

What happens if you indent the contents of verbatim
TeX cannot guess what amount of indentation you start from, because as soon as \begin{verbatim*} is scanned, the spaces before it have been ignored.
Inside the verbatim* environment, spaces at the beginning of lines aren't ignored, because you want to preserve the indentation. So are spaces before \end{verbatim*}.
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
    gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
    vulputate a, magna.
    \begin{verbatim*}
        class Main {

          public static void main(String[] args) {

            int first = 10;
            int second = 20;

            // add two numbers
            int sum = first + second;
            System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = "  + sum);
          }
        }
    \end{verbatim*}
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
    vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
    bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.
\end{document}


Is there any way out?
Yes, just don't overindent your source. Or, if you don't want to follow this advice, load fancyvrb.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
    gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
    vulputate a, magna.
    \begin{Verbatim*}[gobble=8]
        class Main {

          public static void main(String[] args) {

            int first = 10;
            int second = 20;

            // add two numbers
            int sum = first + second;
            System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = "  + sum);
          }
        }
    \end{Verbatim*}
    Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
    Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
    vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
    bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.
\end{document}



You could use a verbatimbox to avoid the issue...even making the verbatim inline, if desired.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{verbbox}C:\Users\me\Programs> test.cpp\end{verbbox}
    guess what?\\
    \hspace*{1em}\theverbbox\\
    the verbatim environment generate an additional empty line at the end as shown in the picture below.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



thanks for your advice.  I found a new solution as shown in the question I re-edit above, it seems that the empty line has nothing to do with the tcolorbox but some association with indentation. do you have any idea about the phenomenon ?

@On_My_Way  Yes, your verbatim environment is indented.  While indentation spaces are normally absorbed by LaTeX, in the case of verbatim environments, they are retained, precisely because they are taken verbatim.

Indentation of \begin{verbatim} is not a problem. No matter if there a spaces or/and black lines before, the verbatim text will start in a new line. Dot.
But indentation of \end{verbatim} is necessarily made INSIDE this environment, and therefore each space or tab count ...




\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{proof of the concept} 
So, respect this:\begin{verbatim*}foo\end{verbatim*}
What happen before have not any effect :
                   \begin{verbatim*}
foo
\end{verbatim*}
But the indentation {\em inside} matters: 

\begin{verbatim*}
foo
                    \end{verbatim*}
And it also matters how you do the indentation:
\begin{verbatim*}
foo
                    \end{verbatim*}
\end{document}

Besides that, note that also matter if after \end{verbatim} there is a blank line. The end  of verbatim text always mean a line break, and some vertical skip, plus the  the normal paragraph vertical skips (that you will notice only when \parskip is not 0pt, e.g., using \usepackage[indent,skip=1em]{parskip} in the preamble)  but not the indentation of the start of a new paragraph, unless when \end{verbatim} is followed by  a \par or blank line  (i.e., a true end of paragraph):



\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}foo\end{verbatim} This text will be NOT indented
\begin{verbatim}foo\end{verbatim} 
This text will be NOT indented
\begin{verbatim}foo\end{verbatim}

This text will be indented
\begin{verbatim}foo\end{verbatim}\par This text will be indented
\end{document}

